# Can i use freeswitch as server for restcomm-android-sdk

Tags: restcomm

i wang to use restcomm-android-sdk to develop my app,but i donot want to use TeleStax server,i want to use myself server. If i can use freeswitch as server? or other server? Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pengwang, in terms of signaling, restcomm-android-sdk uses SIP, which is compatible with freeswitch, the problem is media where restcomm-android-sdk uses Webrtc. If freeswitch is able to use Webrtc for media, then in principle you should be able to use it, but I'm not sure if freeswitch supports Webrtc.

Also, notice that you don't have to use the commercial TeleStax server with restcomm-android-sdk. You can use the community version, which is open source and which you can install locally using docker very easily

Hope this helps,
Antonis Tsakiridis